# Need the sequence Order of Quarters of FY2011-12 based on a date given as input

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

**ASP.NET using C#**

The following are the Quarters for the financial year 2011-12

```
April 2011 to June2011 - Q1
July2011 to Sep2011    - Q2
Oct2011 to Dec2011     - Q3
Jan2012 to March 2012  - Q4
```

**EDIT**:

If i give a date as input then i need the output interms of the Quarter of that month:

Lets consider a date as input is `02-Jan-2012`.

then i need the output as     `Q4`

Lets take another date as input: `31May2012`.

For this i need the output as  `Q1`

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function

```
public string GetQuarter(DateTime date)
{
   // we just need to check the month irrespective of the other parts(year, day)
   // so we will have all the dates with year part common
   DateTime dummyDate = new DateTime(1900, date.Month, date.Day);

   if (dummyDate < new DateTime(1900, 7, 1) && dummyDate >= new DateTime(1900, 4, 1))
   {
      return "Q1";
   }
   else if (dummyDate < new DateTime(1900, 10, 1) && dummyDate >= new DateTime(1900, 7, 1))
   {
       return "Q2";
   }
   else if (dummyDate < new DateTime(1900, 1, 1) && dummyDate >= new DateTime(1900, 10, 1))
   {
       return "Q3";
   }
   else
   {
       return "Q4";
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this could help.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DateRange> range = new List<DateRange>();
//temp filling the data
            DateTime start = new DateTime(2011, 4, 1);
            range.Add(new DateRange() {From=start,To = start.AddMonths(3).AddMilliseconds(-1),Name="Q1"});
            start = range.LastOrDefault().To.AddMilliseconds(1);
            range.Add(new DateRange() { From = start, To = start.AddMonths(3).AddMilliseconds(-1), Name = "Q2" });
            start = range.LastOrDefault().To.AddMilliseconds(1);
            range.Add(new DateRange() { From = start, To = start.AddMonths(3).AddMilliseconds(-1), Name = "Q3" });
            start = range.LastOrDefault().To.AddMilliseconds(1);
            range.Add(new DateRange() { From = start, To = start.AddMonths(3).AddMilliseconds(-1), Name = "Q4" });

            var order = range.OrderByDescending(r => r.IsCurrentQuater(DateTime.Now));
            foreach (var itm in order)
                Console.WriteLine(itm);

        }
    }

    public class DateRange
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime From { get; set; }
        public DateTime To { get; set; }

        public bool IsCurrentQuater(DateTime date)
        {
            return date >= From && date <= To;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1} to {2}", Name, From, To);
        }
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: This is too ambiguious. Need some simple code. It's too big. I updated my question. please have a look.

Comment: just don't look at the way i have created quarters.. you could save quarters in the list any easy way you want.. just concentrate on DateRange class... IsCurrentQuater return true if the date specified between current Quarter range.

Comment: to get only one quarter you can use range.Where(r => r.IsCurrentQuater(DateTime.Now)).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: btw i have used Linq over object because you have specified you are using .net 3.5.. linq is the only way to make you work easy

Comment: 2011 year is just given as example as Year for understanding. I need the Quarter info for any date is given as input. basically i pass datetime.now as input, for this i need output as 'Q1' or 'Q2' or Q3 or Q4 for that current date passed.

Comment: Can you check a way to get the Quarter info with DateTime.Now.Month

Comment: ok.. can you show me the code how did you get quarters info in you application?